# Set variables in stored procedure using EXECUTE sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables, stored-procedures, sp-executesql

I'm trying to build an SQL string to execute via `sp_executesql` but I can't seem to assign value to a declared variable within the passed in sql string.

So below is an example of my procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectRecords]
@psID INT --parameter passed in
AS   
DECLARE @existingRecordCount INT=0

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @paramDefinitions NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @paramDefinitions=
    '@psID INT,    
    @existingRecordCount INT OUTPUT'

SET @sql='  
SELECT 
@existingRecordCount=COUNT(Name)
FROM dbo.Asset_Log
WHERE ID=@psID
GROUP BY Name'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @paramDefinitions, @psID, @existingRecordCount
```

So, I'd expect my record count to be in the `@existingRecordCount` variable but I receive the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'OUPUT'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@existingRecordCount".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: `OUTPUT` not `OUPUT`. Also call like `EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @paramDefinitions, @psID, @existingRecordCount OUTPUT` and declare `@psID` outside and assign it the value to be passed in.

Comment: Can you explain why this needs to be dynamic SQL?

Comment: Martin, thanks. Sorry about the Typo. Aaron, I've just modified the example for this post

Answer (score 5):

While this doesn't need to be dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectRecords]
  @psID INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  DECLARE @rc INT;

  SELECT @rc = COUNT(Name) 
    FROM dbo.Asset_Log
    WHERE ID = @psID;
END
GO
```

I'll assume there is other logic here that you haven't shared that makes it a necessity. If that is the case:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectRecords]
  @psID INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  DECLARE 
    @rc     INT = 0,
    @sql    NVARCHAR(1000),
    @params NVARCHAR(1000);

  SET @params = N'@psID INT, @rc INT OUTPUT';

  SET @sql = N'SELECT @rc = COUNT(Name)
    FROM dbo.Asset_Log
    WHERE ID = @psID;';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @psID, @rc OUTPUT;
END
GO
```

I don't see any reason for `GROUP BY Name`, either. Have you observed how that changes the query from a single result to a row per name?

Comment: Hi Aaron. Thanks for the answer. The group by is actually needed as in the full SQL I have other columns returned

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Dynamic Query` syntax and `Group By Clause`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectRecords]
@psID INT --parameter passed in
AS       
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT COUNT(Name) as existingRecordCount FROM dbo.Asset_Log WHERE ID=@psID
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, Its working**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteItem]
    @ItemId int = 0,
    @status bit OUT

AS
Begin
   DECLARE @cnt int;
   SET @status =0;  --Set value to variable 
   return @status;
End
```

**Execute store procedure**

We are passing ItemId as 6 at the time of execute stored procedure

Out put will receive on "@statuss" variable

```
DECLARE @statuss bit;
EXECUTE  [dbo].[deleteItem] 6, @statuss output;
PRINT @statuss;
```